# Throwing primitive types in C++

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I am working on a dialog that requests a file, username, and password from a user. I want the user to be notified when there is an issue with their selection. The file must be valid before I bother checking the name and password fields of my dialog. I know there are other ways to do this, my question is in regards to the efficiency of this process.

My MFC C++ application has a string table where the strings are identified using macros that map a translation unit to an integer (`#define IDS_SOME_ERROR 100`), where these integers can be used by the MFC framework to load a string from the string table.

I am curious about the efficiency of throwing primitive types, so I looked into the `throw` keyword on [cpprefrence.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw).

> The `throw expression` statement copy-initializes the exception object from expression (this may call the move constructor for rvalue expression, and the copy/move may be subject to copy elision), then transfers control to the exception handler with the matching type whose compound statement or member initializer list was most recently entered and not exited by this thread of execution. Even if copy initialization selects the move constructor, copy initialization from lvalue must be well-formed, and the destructor must be accessible (since C++14).

Here is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472134/what-to-throw-when-throwing-c-exceptions) asking about types to throw, I noticed a comment saying not to throw things like `int` or `string`. Why is this?

Here is my code:

```
void SomeDialog::OnOK()
{   
    UpdateData();

    try
    {
        if (VerifySomeFile(myFileStruct.getPath()))
        {
            if (DialogNameField.IsEmpty())
            {
                throw IDS_ERROR_NOID; // "No name specified."
            }

            if (DialogPasswordField.IsEmpty())
            {
                throw IDS_ERROR_NOPWD; // "No password specified."
            }

            CDialog::OnOK();
        }
        else
        {
            throw IDS_BAD_FILE; // "Bad or expired file."
        }
    }
    catch (int errIDS)
    { 
        CString tempStr;
        tempStr.LoadString(errIDS);
        AfxMessageBox(tempStr, MB_OK);
    }
}
```

Since an `int` is a primitive type in C++, does the `throw` statement still have to perform any copying? Is it safe to throw primitive types in C++ in this fashion? Would it be more efficient to remove the catch block and place my error dialog logic from the `catch` block to each throw location? If I were to do this, I would also have to nest my code such that only one dialog is shown if there is more than one error.

Comment: *"Why is this?"* - As the accepted answer says: *"Don't throw primitive types, since they carry no semantic information."*

Comment: @ChristianHackl, in my case though, I'm less worried about the information the exception contains, and more about control flow. I feel it's nicer to have one control point where a dialog is created, versus having dialogs created throughout my _much more_ complicated source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be worried about *efficiency* too much, since the recommended practice to catch `std::exeption` derivates is to use a `const` reference anyways.

It has the advantage to introduce an exception hierarchy, and provide overridden error messages using `const char* std::exception::what() const`.

Comment: Throwing an exception is by definition also something that shouldn't happen too often, so the performance impact of the throw itself is largely irrelevant anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it would be better to do something like that instead of throwing built-in type:

```
struct SomeError{int errid};
...
throw SomeError{IDS_BAD_FILE};
```

Comment: If you think it is better, you should be able to explain why.

Comment: Depends on where the exception would be caught, I think it is better to throw independent struct(just for the sake of name and catch(the struct)) than build-in type(int here), because something else might also throw int with the same value.

Comment: Now this makes it a fine answer - put the rationale into it!

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin with getting terminology right. C++ doesn't have a concept of a primitive type. In C++, there are built-in types and custom types.

`int`, for this matter, is a built-in type. While from the language perspective throwing an object of type `int` is no different from throwing an object of type `MySpecialClass` or a derivation of `std::exception`, throwing the latter has as a benefit - since this is a well-known exception, one might expect that there would be `catch (const std::exception& e)` somewhere in the program. This catch will handle all derivations of `std::exception`, and would be possible, at the bare minimum, to print the message within the exception.

However, it is not reasonable to expect one to catch an `int`! And even if one does, what next? How this exception is supposed to be handled? Number printed to the console? And what the user should make of it?

Comment: I think I understand the reason to throw `std::exception` derivatives in most cases. but here I'm more concerned about control flow, I'm "abusing" the try-catch block since it means I only need one call-site for my message box, and am mostly curious about the overhead a try--throw-catch block adds to my program.

Comment: @ZevIsert, performance overhead is rather significant. stack unwinding is a costly operation. For that matter, using exceptions as control flow is not recommended when performance is of importance.

Comment: Good point.. But what about this case where I'm catching it in scope? I'm certain that none of the functions called in the try blocks throw integers. There shouldn't (famous last words) be any stack unwinding here should there? Or does the program have to unwind from the `if` blocks?